# gradle commandline how can i use for requirejs building

Tags: gradle

```
task RunTask(type: Exec) {
    println(System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows'))
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init stopTomcat'
}
```

Runtask println true or false print screen
but commandLine does't work
actually I want to do requireJs r.js.cmd and commandLine "cmd", "/c", "path\r.js.cmd", "-o", "build.json" does't work

build.json output file "out" : "test.js"

I don't know, how I do commandLine for gradle

Runtask println true or false print screen
and anyting not appear